# How to work with the two form tags in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

In my aspx page I have a first name, last name `text boxes`, submit `button` in my form tag. And the form action set to an external `url` of my company registration form.

The form is as below.

```
  <form method="post" action="mycompanyurl">
                    <label>First Name:</label>
                    <input name="first_name" />
                   <label>Last Name:</label>
                    <input name="last_name" />
  </form>
```

Now I want to do some server side validations in my aspx.cs file and save data in my local db without affecting the action, that is redirecting to the url.

That is to do validations and redirection.

For this I have taken another form tag and set action to the aspx page

```
<form method="post" action="Default.aspx">
</form>
```

But when I click on the submit it is redirecting to mycompany registration page but no action to my aspx page.

Help me to achieve this

Comment: do you want to post a both forms from one single submit button click?

Comment: Yes on the same submit button click @Bharat

Comment: is it okay i you post both form using ajax?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you

Comment: Yeah it is okay if I use ajax @Bharat

Answer (score 0):

Look, what you have to do is,

take submit button outside of the both forms,

for exam.

```
<form method="post" action="mycompanyurl" id="FormUpload1">
        <label>First Name:</label>
        <input name="first_name" />
        <label>Last Name:</label>
        <input name="last_name" />
    </form>

<form method="post" action="Default.aspx" id="FormUpload2"></form>

<input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-success hidden" />
```

Now onclick of submit button, post both forms, using forms.js

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        $('#btnSubmit').click(function () {
            SubmitForm1()
            SubmitForm2()
        })

        function SubmitForm1() {
            $("#FormUpload1").submit(function () {
                $("#FormUpload1").ajaxSubmit({
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result.Success == true) {
                            //Success code
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Error occured. Please refresh this page and try again.")
                        }
                    }
                })
            })
        }

        function SubmitForm2() {
            $("#FormUpload2").submit(function () {
                $("#FormUpload2").ajaxSubmit({
                    success: function (result) {
                        if (result.Success == true) {
                            //Success code
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Error occured. Please refresh this page and try again.")
                        }
                    }
                })
            })
        }
</script>
```

so, at a time both form will be submitted. but don't forget to include form.js file.

Comment: Can you share a example pls, bcoz I have no idea about forms.js

Comment: hey CA, do you got your answer?

Comment: No, I haven't got it yet @Bharat